# Relogin and retry request in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to do automatic relogin and retry request (in case of success) if I get 401 error from the server. I'm using Volley lib. As far as I can see from the Volley sources it runs in while (true) loop until it get a response or exception:

```
@Override
public NetworkResponse performRequest(Request<?> request){
    while (true) {
        try {
            httpResponse = mHttpStack.performRequest(request, headers);
            return httpResponse;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED || statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
                attemptRetryOnException("auth", request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I'd like to stop this loop until I get successful login response and then continue attempts to get response.

Is there any way to do it in custom RetryPolicy without modifications in Volley sources ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement own `RetryPolicy` and override `public void retry(VolleyError error)` method like this:

```
    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
        {
            throw new VolleyError("Client is not authorized, retry is pointless");
        }
    }
```